# string to code in html

Tags: javascript, html

H have a variable like this:

```
var players_data = [];
players_data[1] = {
    name : 'dave',
    robot : "robotron"
};
```

I have a bit of code for putting a string together:

```
string="players_data["+ current_player + "].name"
```

which returns `players_data[1].name` and not `dave`

Can someone explain this a little, or answer how I make the html read the string as a bit of code, not just the string? Im sure this  has been answered, but I dont even know the correct terminology to search for it properly!

OK, what I have given is really an example of a big problem Im having with javascript. Basically, I want to be able to use variables to make the string, so I might want to use .name or .robot, so the string assembler would then use whichever value was in the end variable.

Sorry to be such a noob!

Comment: Remove the quotes, and you're good.

Comment: `players_data[current_player].name` without the string is the correct way to get "dave". Do you have any special requirement that forces you to use a string? If so, please ask a more precise question - otherwise, this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: OK, what I have given is really an example of a big problem Im having with javascript. Basically, I want to be able to use variables to make the string, so I might want to use .name or .robot, so the string assembler would then use whichever value was in the end variable.

Sorry to be such a noob!

Answer (score 6):

It should work with:

```
var str = players_data[current_player].name;
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - Yes, you are right, `eval` is wrong to use here, but in most cases, using `eval` alone is not enough to execute scripts and malicious content that can infect someone, as it only runs in the local instance of the webpage.

Comment: A local instance of your website is all one needs.